# Why, in javascript, is `2 << -1` zero instead of one?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I came across this rather strange behaviour of the bitwise shift-left operator, and I'd like to understand it better...

Let's say we want to build a function that receives an integer and return the associated integer power of two, i.e.:

`power => Math.pow(2, power)`

A more efficient way of doing this would be to use the shift-left bitwise operator (let's say overflows are not a problem):

`power => 1 << power`

And this works fine. The strange thing is that this should work too:

`power => 2 << (power-1)`

because it follows from:

- `2 == 1 << 1` *(bitwise encoding of 2)*
- `(a << b) << c == a << (b + c)` *(semantics of `<<`)*

However this is not the case, because:

`2 << -1 == 0`

So, the second law fails:

`0 == 2 << -1 == (1 << 1) << -1` **!=** `1 << (1 + -1) == 1 << 0 == 1`

At first I thought it was some problem with shifting by negative numbers, maybe js was interpreting any shift by negative number as zero? However that's also not the case, because for instance:

`1 << -31 == 2`

As expected. And more to the point:

`2 << 31 == 2 << -1 == 0`

So... what is going on here? Testing all values of shifts for `2`, all of them yield the expected value, except for the numbers congruent to -1 mod 32, even the positive ones, which yield zero instead of one.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You're actually left shifting by  `31` http://es5.github.io/#x11.7.1 point 6 and 7, Let _rnum_ be `ToUint32(rval)`, 7. then truncates this to 5 bits.

Comment: In C, bit-wise shifting left with a negative shift count is undefined per ISO 9899:2011 6.5.7.

Comment: You started with the wrong assumption that shifting with a negative number changes the direction of the shift. This is mathematically correct because shifting is multiplication with a power of `2` but this is not how shifting is implemented in programming languages. During compilation the shifting operation is translated to the corresponding processor operation; most/all nowadays processors provide shifting as primitive operations. The processor shifts the bits to the left or to the right, it doesn't know mathematics and doesn't handle negative shifts. The shift value is treated as unsigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple, all you have to is follow the steps defined by ecmascript standard:

[Ecmascript << operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-left-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

According to this, when you do 2 << -1:

- -1 is passed to unsiged int 32, which means 4294967295 (-1 >>> 0)
- only the 5 least significants bits are considered: 4294967295 & 0x1F = 31
- 2 << 31 gives us 0

Comment: wow... I was under the impression that bitwise shift operators in javascript were circular because of the behaviour of 1 << a. As it turns out, it's only circular for that particular case -_-. In the other cases it does this weird truncation :/